# Why is C# app not aborted despite the required global option missing?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, system.commandline

I have difficulties understanding how the System.CommandLine works and have prepared a short [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1OXImJ) to demonstrate my issue.

I am trying to create a C# console app, which would be called with `--nodes` option and be passed one or many numerical ids:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Option<long[]> nodesOption = new("-n", "--nodes")
    {
        Arity = ArgumentArity.OneOrMore,
        Description = "Numerical node ids",
        IsRequired = true,
    };

    RootCommand rootCommand = new("A test app for saving node ids");
    rootCommand.AddGlobalOption(nodesOption);
    await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);

    Console.WriteLine("Why is this line printed?");
}
```

When I call the above code however without specifying any options, it does print the warning `Option '-n' is required.`, but the execution is not aborted.

Shouldn't the app exit with code 1 when an `isRequired` global option is missing?

If it shouldn't, how can I change the app behaviour to exit with code 1?

And also I wonder, how to specify a `new[] { 1234567890 }` as the default value for the option, I cannot find it in the [System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/) doc.

Below is a screenshot of my test case and its output:

[image: screenshot with C# code]

Comment: have you tried to [open an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/command-line-api/issues) on their github? i do curious about this one too, perhaps it was by design.

Comment: Generally I like opening GitHub issues, but here I think I just haven't fully understand the usage doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the execution of a command is not supposed to terminate the whole application, that is by design of the command-linetoolset.

Now, for the detecting. The `rootCommand.InvokeAsync` method would return non-zero result if not completed successfully. So, in your case simply check for the output:

```
int result = await rootCommand.InvokeAsync(args);

if (result != 0)
{
    // Handle the failure of the rootCommand's call.
    return;
}
```

As for the default value, there is actually an overload which allows you to specify a delegate which in turn should provide default values if none are input by the user:

```
Option<long[]> nodesOption = new(
    new[] { "-n", "--nodes" }, // Your aliases
    () => new[] { 1234567890L } // The delegate with the default values.
)
```

Comment: I should add that everything I found out can be directly viewed by VS's intellisense. So I suggest to start using it every day ^^